# WebSocket Namespaces

Tags: javascript, websocket

I'm trying to look in the MDN documentation for when you do `new WebSocket()`, is there a way to only send a message to users that are subscribed to a certain room/namespace?

Answer (score 2):

No.A websocket is just a transport, if you need that kind of publisher/subscriber functionality, you will have to put in place a message broker or a framework that provides you that functionality.

You can create yours by using RabbitMQ, ZeroMQ or even Redis for example, or use frameworks specialized in that kind of functionality like SignalR (.NET), Faye (NodeJS), etc...